# Cant get rhodes app to run on iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, rhodes

I tried running a demo application and a basic rhogen app application and cant get anything to load on my device even though it works fine in the simulator. Here is the error I get:

```
I 10/10/2011 17:20:53:800 0505f000                  APP| Create RHO framework failed: #<ArgumentError: NULL pointer given>;Trace: lib/rholang/localization_simplified.rb:27:in `get_property'
lib/rholang/localization_simplified.rb:27:in `requre_loc'
lib/rholang/localization_simplified.rb:56:in `<main>'
lib/rho/rhoapplication.rb:29:in `require'
lib/rho/rhoapplication.rb:29:in `<main>'
lib/rhoframework.rb:157:in `require'
lib/rhoframework.rb:157:in `<main>'
```

Is there something specific I need to change in my build or Xcode to get it running?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else struggles with this sort of thing: there should have been a nil check on lib/rholang/localization_simplified.rb:27.

If you are having problems with this, dont rule out the fact that there might be a bug in Rhodes source...

Comment: And as it is an open source project, should you find a bug, please let them know about it so it can be resolved.